# I get Exception unknown error, after querying DataBase for the second time in PHP MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm using this code:

```
class db extends mysqli
{
    protected static $instance;
    protected static $options = array();

    private function __construct() {
        $o = self::$options;

        // turn of error reporting
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_OFF);

        // connect to database
        @parent::__construct(isset($o['host'])   ? $o['host']   : 'localhost',
                             isset($o['user'])   ? $o['user']   : 'root',
                             isset($o['pass'])   ? $o['pass']   : '',
                             isset($o['dbname']) ? $o['dbname'] : 'world',
                             isset($o['port'])   ? $o['port']   : 3306,
                             isset($o['sock'])   ? $o['sock']   : false );

        // check if a connection established
        if( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
            throw new exception(mysqli_connect_error(), mysqli_connect_errno()); 
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if( !self::$instance ) {
            self::$instance = new self(); 
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function setOptions( array $opt ) {
        self::$options = array_merge(self::$options, $opt);
    }

    public function query($query) {
        if( !$this->real_query($query) ) {
            throw new exception( $this->error, $this->errno );
        }

        $result = new mysqli_result($this);
        return $result;
    }

    public function prepare($query) {
        $stmt = new mysqli_stmt($this, $query);
        return $stmt;
    }    
}
```

I have some functions that update, insert, display DB content.

Now if I execute this code directly, no problem:

```
$sql = db::getInstance();
$sql->set_charset("utf8");
$sql->query("UPDATE ads SET text='moooo' WHERE id=1") ;
```

But if I use two functions one to display some content and the second to update, I get an unknown exception error and DB won't be updated!

Here is an example where I get error:

```
$sql = db::getInstance();   
$sql->set_charset("utf8"); 
if(ad_exists($mq->id)){
$sql->query("UPDATE ads SET text='moooo' WHERE id=1") ;
}
```

And here is how the ad_exist function looks like:

```
function ad_exists($id){
    $sql = db::getInstance();   
    $sql->set_charset("utf8");  
    $result = $sql1->query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE id=".$id);
    $sql->close();
    if($result->num_rows>0) {$result->close();
    return true;}
    else {$result->close();
        return false;}
}
```

I've been going about closing connections after queries, preparing statements instead of direct queries, trying to make db object global or passing it as a variable, nothing seems to work, can't get over this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo error in here:

```
$result = $sql1->query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE id=".$id);
```

the **1** after $sql shouldn't be there, also try not to initiate two objects, you can pass the $sql variable into your ad_exists method and just use the `$result = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE id=".$id);` line, don't close the connection after the UPDATE is done.

Try this:

In your ad_exists method:

```
function ad_exists($id, &$sql) {
    $result = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE id=".$id);
    if($result->num_rows>0) {
        $result->close();
        return true;
    } else {
        $result->close();
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your code where you call your ad_exists method:

```
$sql = db::getInstance();   
$sql->set_charset("utf8"); 
if(ad_exists($mq->id, $sql)) {
    $sql->query("UPDATE ads SET text='moooo' WHERE id=1") ;
}
$sql->close();
```

Comment: Thanks, this did work. Although I still don't understand what the problem was. If would be great if you can explain.

Comment: When you pass the db object to the function as a parameter you are actually sending a copy of it, hence there are two objects now, why is this different than instantiating a new one!?

Comment: I think your approach will work maybe it was just the typo, is doing the same thing but I just optimize some code, if you still want to use the same variable for the connection, try using Classes to get things a lot better, don't use global variables.

Comment: Did some more changes, you may want to take a look

Comment: Passed $sql referenced in your method (see the & before $sql)